# entity reference filter condition

Tags: views

I have created view and I have added the fields like entity reference fields followed by content fields, then I added the entity reference field in filter condition, but its not displaying the table data.
Following methods I followed to create the filter conditions,

1] created new view added the entity reference and other content fields.

2]added the contextual filters as shown in screen attachment, also the relationship as entity reference of the field.

3]in the left view page-> clicked on ->add filter condition->chosen the field and relationship but still its not able to filter the data of table please help me on this.thanks in advance[image]

[image]

Comment: Please remove 'LAB ID' from contexual filter and then check.

Comment: @deepa: i removed the lab id, but no changes its the same.

Comment: remove from relationships too and check on page url.

Comment: @VimalGoradiya: i removed relationship too, its the same i am not getting why i am not able filter the data using entity fields.

Comment: I am not understand why you want use entity reference in this view you already get LAB ID without referencing.

Comment: @vimal:if i add the field directly in add filter condition, then also its not showing the result so i thought since its entity reference field might need to add the contextual fields

Answer (score 0):

In my observation it appears you are mixing some configurations here. Normally when you add **Content: Nid**, you are telling the view to get the NID from your URL like animal-info-view/% where "%" represents the node ID or somewhere else like Panels but notice that you don't have that. The view will now be asking "Where is my nid? I can't find it.". So now you're having issues with no data being displayed.

If you need a listing page, sometimes you won't need the Contextual and Relationship fields anymore. Just directly add the entity reference field into Filter Criteria and it should look like the Gender filter.

If you need a content/node view page, now you will need the Contextual fields but kinda not need the filter because you're just displaying one content.

**EDITED**

Apologies for the late reply. So on my research I found a module called [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) that enabled you to assign a View to provide the selections for your filter. So install an enable the module.

### Create the Entity Reference filter view

1. Create a new View.
2. Add a new Views Display called Entity Reference.
3. Select the Lab content type for the **Show** field.
4. Add the Lab Nid and Title/Name.
5. Under Format, replace it with **Entity Reference List**
6. Under the format's settings, choose **Nid** for Search fields.

   You should have something like:
   [image]

### Tweak your Animal Info View

1. Remove all the Contextual filters and Relationships you have and the **(Content entity referenced from field_lab_idc) Content: LAB ID** filter you added.
2. And add the **Content: LAB ID** field that's in your *Animal Info* content type
3. On the LAB ID's settings pop-up, you will notice something new, it's the **View used to select the entities**. Select the entity reference view that we created a while ago.
4. You can leave the default **Operator** setting to **Is one of**.
5. Check the **Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it**.

   This would look like:
   [image]
6. And click Apply.

   Your Animal Info View should have something like this:
   [image]

Hope this helps you.

**NOTE:** Please include your requirements so that people would know what you want the result to be like.

Comment: @ Leolando Tan:Thanks, but i tried to add directly like as you mentioned but its not showing the table data again.

Comment: Oh! :( What is your requirement for this View? Is it a listing page or a single content page?

Comment: @ Leolando Tan: listing of created content fields.where in i have fields type like entity reference, text, date.

Comment: @kashish I see and Lab ID referenced is just another node right? I'll try to replicate your setup and update my answer.

Comment: @kashish I added a guide on my solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Leolando Tan:loads of thanks , i will try with this.thanks a lot it means a lot to me.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it can help you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Views Autocomplete Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) module ..it should be work for applying filter with view relationship.

To configure this watch the following tutorial by Daily Dose of Drupal "[Watch here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQtwIwAmoVChMI4PDZxenGxwIVSwOOCh3IkwCO&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DCkyIYnYswko&ei=IrvdVeDXK8uGuATIp4LwCA&usg=AFQjCNGfULwiHCA9kcqIYKc5zlaHYdzLaQ)"